# Is there a list of programs for yum

Tags: linux, package-management, yum

Basically I would like to know if there's is an actual web page that can be searched for the programs available under yum. I have yumex and I've tried using it but its super slow to search (sometimes it takes 5 minutes) and I would like some webpage or other method of doing a search.

thanks,

Comment: Debian and Gentoo have an online package index...I'd be surprised if yum doesn't have one too. I can't find it though :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you just want a big list/overview of all available packages or that you're specifically searching for something like "ftp".

In the latter you could use

`yum search ftp`

or any other terms you want to search for.

If you use YUM under Fedora core you can also look here -> [Fedora Package DB](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/)

Answer (score 0):

"yum list all" lists all packages available in your configured repos. It's slow, so I stash the output somewhere to look at when I've some quick need for it.

"yum info all" gets not just the package names and versions (and origins), but also a brief description of each.